# variable defined in settimeout function returns as undefined outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, charactercount

Please find the code below:

```
setTimeout(function() {
var objTextareaText = objTextArea.innerText;
var normalizedText = objTextareaText;
                        if (!countSpacesAsChars) {
                            normalizedText = objTextareaText.replace(/\s/g,"").replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");}
                        strText = normalizedText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,    "").replace(/&nbsp;/gi, " ");         
                        //Strip Html tags
                        strText = normalizedText.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").replace(/^([\t\r\n]*)$/, "");
                    }, 50);
if (strText.length >= MaxLength) {

}
```

From the above if statement strText is returning as undefined.

Also if i include the if statement inside the settimeout function as below:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var objTextareaText = objTextArea.innerText;
                var normalizedText = objTextareaText;
                if (!countSpacesAsChars) {
                    normalizedText = objTextareaText.replace(/\s/g,    "").replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");
                }
                strText = normalizedText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").replace(/&nbsp;/gi, " ");         
                //Strip Html tags
                strText =         normalizedText.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").replace(/^([\t\r\n]*)$/, "");

                if ((e.data.domEvent.$.keyCode === 8) ||     (e.data.domEvent.$.keyCode === 46) || ((e.data.domEvent.$.shiftKey) 
                    && (e.data.domEvent.$.keyCode === 36)) || ((e.data.domEvent.$.shiftKey) && (e.data.domEvent.$.keyCode === 35)) 
                    || (e.data.domEvent.$.keyCode === 35) || (e.data.domEvent.$.keyCode === 36) || (e.data.domEvent.$.keyCode === 37) 
                    || (e.data.domEvent.$.keyCode === 38) || (e.data.domEvent.$.keyCode === 39) || (e.data.domEvent.$.keyCode === 40)) {
                    showCharacterCount();
                    e.cancelBubble = false;
                    e.returnValue = true;
                    return true;
                }
                // Reaches Max Length - Shows error MAX_VALUE Reached Error Msg.
                if (strText.length >= MaxLength) {
                    showCharacterCount();
                    e.cancelBubble = true;
                    e.returnValue = false;
                    e.cancel();
                    e.stop();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    showCharacterCount(strText);
                    e.cancelBubble = false;
                    e.returnValue = true;
                    return true;
                }
          }, 50);
```

By above way there is an issue with key events.

```
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.returnValue = false;
                    e.cancel();
                    e.stop();
                    return false;
```

These code will not work.

So please suggest a solution. 
Please Note: Settimeout function should be used as i am getting the count of the characters from RTF in salesforce.

Comment: You should clean up your question and go straight to the point and not add tons of unnecessary details

Answer (score 1):

Use below code as there Closure added to setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {

var objTextareaText = objTextArea.innerText;
var normalizedText = objTextareaText;
                        if (!countSpacesAsChars) {
                            normalizedText = objTextareaText.replace(/\s/g,"").replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");}
                        strText = normalizedText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,    "").replace(/&nbsp;/gi, " ");         
                        //Strip Html tags
                        strText = normalizedText.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").replace(/^([\t\r\n]*)$/, "");



//change below code line as closure
  }(), 50);


// now strText is not undefined 
if (strText.length >= MaxLength) {

 }
```

If you want to use setTimeout variable value outside it , then can do using closure function , because it(a closure function) has access to outside , inside and within a function. more info at [closure function](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: try to explain what the mistake and how to solve it too

Comment: If you want to use setTimeout variable value outside it , then can do  using closure function , becas it(a closure function) has access to outside , inside and within a function. more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: I am not having the problem brother. I said, edit your answer and update with details. In SO, we all are expecting a god quality answer. I can leave a detailed answer and it may get accepted. But I value your efforts. In order to get more votes and get accepted, post a good quality answer

Comment: As said, +1. But your answer should be more detailed. Check some answers to Well received questions and you will find how